# How can I horizontally align an element with another element directly beneath it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make a grid of "clock" elements (5 to a line), with a DAY and DATE directly beneath each one, centered with the clock (day on one line, date right below it). I am new to html/css so bear with me. Currently, for the first line of 5 clocks, I have:

```
<div class="clock">

<h4><canvas id="piechart0" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
<h4><canvas id="piechart1" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
<h4><canvas id="piechart2" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
<h4><canvas id="piechart3" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
<h4><canvas id="piechart4" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>

<div class="date" id="day0"></div>
<div class="date" id="day1"></div>
<div class="date" id="day2"></div>
<div class="date" id="day3"></div>
<div class="date" id="day4"></div>

<div class="date1" id="date0"></div>
<div class="date1" id="date1"></div>
<div class="date1" id="date2"></div>
<div class="date1" id="date3"></div>
<div class="date1" id="date4"></div>
<script>
    Clock.getDates();
</script>
```

where Clock.getDates() simply sets the dates for the "day" and "date" id's. 
Here is the CSS I have for these:

```
h4 {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.clock {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.date {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.date1 {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
}
canvas {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 25%
}
```

- Goal 1: Have lines of 5 clocks (seen above as "piecharts") where the
  two lines of text underneath each clock is centered with respect to
  the clock.
- Goal 2: Have the five clocks (150px wide and tall) maintain
  70px between eachother.

What is the best way to reach these two goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Put the components for each clock into a wrapper:

```
<clock>

<div class="clockwrapper">
  <h4><canvas id="piechart0" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
  <div class="date" id="day0"></div>
  <div class="date1" id="date0"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
  <h4><canvas id="piechart1" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
  <div class="date" id="day1"></div>
  <div class="date1" id="date1"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
  <h4><canvas id="piechart2" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
  <div class="date" id="day2"></div>
  <div class="date1" id="date2"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
<h4><canvas id="piechart3" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
  <div class="date" id="day3"></div>
  <div class="date1" id="date3"></div>
  </div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
  <h4><canvas id="piechart4" width="150" height="150"></canvas></h4>
  <div class="date" id="day4"></div>
  <div class="date1" id="date4"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

2.) CSS:

Define the wrappers as inline-blocks, adding the margins you want for distances. Define all the included elements as blocks which are centered in the wrapper (and at the same time horizontally center-aligned to each other) by `margin: 0 auto`:

```
.clockwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 35px 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.clockwrapper > * {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Erase the now unnecessary stuff from the other CSS rules

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**For Goal 1:**
Each clock should be contained in a block. Think of them as components, ok? And then align the texts in the center with their paragraphs using 100% width of their container (that's default, you don't have to set it as long as each clock is in a container).

**For Goal 2:**
Float your clocks (literally `float: left;`) it will work while they have a `width` set.